# Idiomatic way in Rust to dump slice contents onto an array?

Tags: arrays, rust, copy, slice

I was doing something like this:

```rust
type HashId = [u8; 32];

fn fill_hash_id(hash_id: &mut HashId, hash_data: &[u8]) {
    for i in 0..32 {
        hash_id[i] = hash_data[i];
    }
    ()
}
```

Is there a better, more direct or idiomatic way for this in Rust?

Comment: [`copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice)?

Comment: Nit: writing `()` at the end of a function is quite redundant and can be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a comment on your question into a full answer:

The [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.slice.html) method [`copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice) will work.

Because an an array `[T; N]` implements [`AsMut<[T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsMut.html)* (that is, a reference to a mutable array of `T` can be treated as a mutable *slice* of `T`), you can call this method on an array.

```rust
type HashId = [u8; 32];

fn main() {
    let mut hash_id: HashId = [0u8; 32];
    let hash_data = vec![1u8; 32];
    
    hash_id.copy_from_slice(&hash_data);
    
    println!("{:?}", &hash_id);
    // bunch of '1's
}
```

But be careful; `copy_from_slice` will panic if the target and receiver aren't the same length.

*Full disclosure: `[T; N]` also implements [`BorrowMut<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.BorrowMut.html), and while I'm *pretty* sure `AsMut` is the trait that's in play here, I'm not 100% sure it's not `BorrowMut`.